# Apollo cache modify doesn't delete the cached item field when DELETE sentinel object is returned

Tags: javascript, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm trying to delete a field in the cached item by using the **cache.modify** method like it's described in the [official documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction#example-deleting-a-field-from-a-cached-object). 
Based on the API docs I should return the
[DELETE sentinel object](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/cache/InMemoryCache/#delete) from the `resolver` function that reflects the type field I want to delete.

I'm doing it but the required field still exists in the cached item after the execution. 
 How it's possible? Have I just missed something?

Here is the code example:

I have this item in the cache

```
{
  __typename:"Module"
  id:"l_14"
  length:223
  title: "Chris Hadfield"
}
```

and I want to delete the `title` field so I tried to use the `cache.modify` as described in the docs. Here is how it looks:

```
  client.cache.modify({
    id: 'Module:l_14',
    fields: {
      title(data, { DELETE }) {
        return DELETE;
      },
    },
  });
```

But after the execution, the appropriate Module item in the cache didn't change. The `title` field hadn't been deleted. It looks exactly like it was before the execution:

```
{
  __typename:"Module"
  id:"l_14"
  length:223
  title: "Chris Hadfield"
}
```

So why the `title` field hadn't been deleted even when I replicated all the steps from the documentation example? 
P.S. I'm not sure if it's relevant, probably not, but just in case: this Item doesn't have a direct mutation etc. in the BE schema. It's just a nested object of the parent one. The schema looks like this:

```
  type Track {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    author: Author!
    thumbnail: String
    length: Int
    modulesCount: Int
    description: String
    numberOfViews: Int
    modules: [Module!]!
  }

  type Module {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    length: Int  
   }
```

Thanks for any help!